# multiple ultragrids bound to the same datasource

Tags: c#, data-binding, ultrawingrid

I'm using ultraTextEditors to embed multiselect ultragrids. I set up the datasource in the form_load event. The facilities is a list.

```
ultraGrid1.DataSource = facilities;
ultraGrid2.DataSource = facilities;
```

The grid loads fine, but if I select rows in the first grid, the selected rows are set in the second grid. How do I disable this?

Also, I can't get selected row into the text editor from ultragrid2. I use AfterEditorButtonCloseUp event to do this. The first grid has the same code and it works fine. What am I missing here?

```
private void utxtExcludeReport_AfterEditorButtonCloseUp(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.EditorButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ultraGrid2.Selected.Rows.Count == 0)
                utxtExcludeReportLab.Text = string.Empty;
            else if (ultraGrid2.Selected.Rows.Count == 1)
                utxtExcludeReportLab.Text = ultraGrid2.Selected.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
            else
                utxtExcludeReportLab.Text = "<multiple>";
        }
```

Comment: Is this Visual Basic? C#? It might help if you added on of those tags ^^

Answer (score 0):

Before you set the datasource for the second ultragrid, you need to create a new BindingContext for it, otherwise events raised by the datasource will be propagated to both grids.

For example (off the top of my head, so it may need refining:

```
ultraGrid2.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
ultraGrid2.DataSource = facilities;
```